# MVVM Toolkit Messenger does not register message

Tags: c#, maui

When I send the selected test in the EditTest() command from the MainPageViewModel class, the message in the CreateTestPageViewModel class does not respond to the sending.
[Github](https://github.com/Kowari1/Test-Builder/tree/master/Test%20Builder)

```cs
public class TestMessage : ValueChangedMessage<Test>
{
    public TestMessage(Test value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

sender

```cs
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainPageViewModel(IFileService fileService)
    {
        this.fileService = fileService;
        Tests = new ObservableCollection<Test>(fileService.OpenFileDirectiry
                (System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),   "*.txt"));
    }
        
    private readonly IFileService fileService;

    public ObservableCollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Test selectedTest;

    #region COMMANND
    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task GoToCreateTestPage()
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(CreateTestPage)}");
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void RemoveTest()
    {
        fileService.DeleteFile(selectedTest.PathFile);
        Tests.Remove(selectedTest);
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task EditTest()
    {           
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new TestMessage(SelectedTest));
        await GoToCreateTestPage();            
    }
    #endregion

    #region METHODS
    #endregion
}
```

recipient

```cs
public partial class CreateTestPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public CreateTestPageViewModel(IFileService fileService)
    {
        this.fileService = fileService;
        Questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();

        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<TestMessage>(
            this,
            (recipient, message) =>
        {
             MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                testName = message.Value.Name;
                IEnumerable<Question> questions = message.Value.Questions;
                Questions.Add((Question)questions);
            });
        });           
    }

    private readonly IFileService fileService;

    public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }                 
        
    private Question selectedQuestion;
    public Question SelectedQuestion
    {
        get => selectedQuestion;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref selectedQuestion, value);              
        }
    }

    private IItem selectedItem;
    public IItem SelectedItem
    {
        get => selectedItem;
        set 
        {
            SetProperty(ref selectedItem, value);
        }
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string testName;
}
```

I didn’t do anything because I can’t even imagine what could help.

Comment: you have to register the listener **before** you send the message

Comment: Can you tell me more about the listener, or send me an article. When creating messages, I was guided only by this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/maui/communicating-between-components

Comment: What don't you understand?  The answer from @julian explains it in more detail, but its a basic logic problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `CreateTestPage` class's constructor takes an instance of `CreateTestViewModel` as an argument, you need to switch the sending of the message and the navigation to the page around.

Try changing this:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
async Task EditTest()
{
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new TestMessage(SelectedTest));
    await GoToCreateTestPage();            
}
```

To this:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
async Task EditTest()
{
    await GoToCreateTestPage();   
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new TestMessage(SelectedTest));            
}
```

If you send the message before you create the page, then the ViewModel might not be instantiated, yet. Thus, it cannot receive the message, because it only starts subscribing to messages **after** the first one was sent *(there is no message queue that allows messages to be received even if subscribing later)*.

Now, this should solve your issue, but I wonder why you even need to send that message. You could [pass the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data), e.g. `SelectedTest`, as navigation parameters, instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to first create a page and then send a message, but it didn’t help, I also understood that the message could not be sent since the page had not yet been created, but I didn’t know about the navigation parameters, I’ll study this topic in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

That is related to [shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0). When I use the [Relative Routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0#relative-routes), the Messenger does work.

You may perform navigation following the below steps referring to the [Register detail page routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0),

1.In AppShell.cs, add

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("CreateTestPage", typeof(CreateTestPage));
```

Then you don't need to define **CreateTestPage** in Shell visual hierarchy. Just **delete** the following code in xaml,

```
<ShellContent
    Title="CreateTestPage"
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:CreateTestPage}"
    Route="CreateTestPage" />
```

2.Perform navigation. You could refer to [Relative routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0#relative-routes) for more info

```
    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task GoToCreateTestPage()
    {

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("CreateTestPage");
    }
```